# Porting from gridgain to ignite - what the ignite equivalents for these gridgain methods

Tags: gridgain, ignite

In porting our code base from gridgain to ignite, I've found similar / renamed methods for most of the ignite methods. There are a few that I need to clarify though.

1. What is the ignite equivalent for

   ```
       //Listener for asynchronous local node grid events. You can subscribe for local node grid event notifications via {@link GridEventStorageManager#addLocalEventListener
       public interface GridLocalEventListener extends EventListener {}
   ```
2. What is the recommended way to invoke a compute future. See picture for compile failures.

Apart from that, it looks like future.listenAsync() should be future.listen()

```
        final ProcessingTaskAdapter taskAdapter = new ProcessingTaskAdapter(task, manager, node);
        ComputeTaskFuture<ProcessingJob> future = grid.cluster()
                .forPredicate(this) //===> what should this be
                .compute().execute(taskAdapter, job);
        future.listen(new IgniteInClosure<IgniteFuture<ProcessingJob>>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(IgniteFuture<ProcessingJob> future) {
                try {
                    // Need this to extract the remote exception, if one occurred
                    future.get();
                } catch (IgniteException e) {
                    manager.fail(e.getCause() != null ? e.getCause() : e);
                } finally {
                    manager.finishJob(job);
                    jobDistributor.distribute(taskAdapter.getSelectedNode());
                }
            }
```

[image: GridGain vs Ignite]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no special class anymore, you simply use `IgnitePredicate` as a listener. Refer to [1] for details.
2. Refer to [2] for information about async support. Also note that projections were replaced with cluster groups [3] (one of your compile errors is because of that). And you're correct, `listenAsync` was renamed to `listen`.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/events

[2] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/async-support

[3] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-groups

Comment: Re 2. do you mean something like this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/074aa436a39f85e23f25e871894fc59f

Comment: I forgot one part in the gist snippet I posted. How do I submit one of our processing jobs and still get a future.

In our old code, we did this 
    ComputeTaskFuture<ProcessingJob> future = grid.cluster()
                    .forPredicate(this)
                    .compute().execute(taskAdapter, job);

In the new code, I could do the following, but the future isn't associated with the execute since the execute returns a processing job instance (one of our classes)
    ProcessingJob j = asyncCompute.execute(taskAdapter, job);

Comment: In async mode `execute` will always return `null`. You should call `future()` method right after calling `execute` to get the associated future.

Comment: Like this, I guess. Thanks 
    `final IgniteCompute asyncCompute = grid.compute(grid.cluster().forPredicate(this)).withAsync();

            asyncCompute.execute(taskAdapter, job);

            final ComputeTaskFuture<ProcessingJob> future = asyncCompute.future();`